# Translate sequentially assigned number in grid to x-y coordinates

Tags: algorithm

Say I have a grid of 5x5, with each cell in the grid numbered from 0-24, going from left to right. Given a cell number such as 17, how do I determine that cell's x and y coordinates? I've been able to do it vice versa, where if given the coordinates I can calculate cell number:

`Cellnumber = x + y∗width`
(The x and y coordinates represent the upper left point of each cell)

But now I want the opposite. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming 0-based coordinates and a C-like syntax, it would be something like this:

```
int y = Cellnumber / width;
int x = Cellnumber % width;
```

Answer (score 7):

With the notation that `%` is the modulus operator:

```
x = Cellnumber % width  
y = Floor(Cellnumber / width)
```

So in your 5 x 5 example, `Cellnumber` = 17

```
   x = 2
   y = 3
```

Comment: I like it, but if one of them needs floor, they both do, or neither does :-)

Comment: @glowcoder : the modulus operator is usually an integer operator...but I take your point.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
Y = (cellnum / 5) + 1   
X = (cellnum % 5) + 1
```

Comment: depends on where you center your coordinate system. I centered cell 0 on (1,1)

Comment: By the time i posted that two other people had responded already. Sorry