# C# array position

Tags: c#, image-processing

I know its a dumb question, but to find value of x and y in an array using index position, can we do it ?

```
int [,] Values = new int [Width,Height];
for (int Xcount = 0; Xcount < Width; Xcount++)
{
     for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < Height; Ycount++)
     {
         Color col = img.GetPixel(Xcount, Ycount);
         if (col.R > 140 && col.G > 140 && col.B > 140)
         {              
              Values[Xcount , Ycount]++;
              file.WriteLine("X :" + Xcount + "  Y :" + Ycount);
              count++;
         }
    }
}
```

How can i get the value of X and Y at index position 0 and last index position i.e count;
I need the fist and last values to be used in further processing 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Is it `Values[0, 0]` and `Values[Width - 1, Height - 1]`?

Comment: Tried them, i need to use them as points in making a line

Comment: This is a pretty slow way to read image data, take a look at this approach. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229672.aspx

Comment: i think this question might be less about array position and more about for loops and counter logic - the value of an array A at position x is A[x] every time no matter what...

Comment: Your question is not clear at all... could you try to explain in detail what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're trying to look for here? Why would it just be `Values[0,0]` for the index position @ zero?

Comment: 0,0 would be the index position of the first value of X and Y - i need those plus index value at last position i.e count-1,count-1 is needed, in all 4 (2 for X and 2 for Y)points for making a line !

Comment: @Don so are you trying to find the x and y position of the element that satisfies your conditions where `col.R > 140 && col.G > 140 && col.B > 140`?

Comment: @cfarm yes , get values of X and Y at the start and end position i.e index 0 and count -1

Comment: @Don do you mean you just want the height and width of your 2D array?

Comment: @cfarm  i have the height and width , i need values of X and Y at first and last position

Comment: @Don so first postion is (0,0) and last position is logically what? is it where `col.R > 140 && col.G > 140 && col.B > 140`?

Comment: @Cfarm col.R > 140 && col.G > 140 && col.B > 140 is the filtering criteria

Comment: @Don sorry, i still don't understand what you are asking. there could be multiple pixels that have this criteria and thus would not be the 'last' position.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to obtain the `x` and `y` indexes from a single position value?

If so, I just answered a question like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750855/simple-question-about-grid-coordinates/5750871#5750871).

Comment: Sorry other way around, from position 0,0 i need the values of X and Y

Comment: So just do the reverse: `int pos = (x * Width) + y;`

Comment: i know the position i.e 0,0 need the separate values of X and Y .Hope the question is clear!

Comment: appreciate your help and reply !

Answer (score 0):

To find the first and last pixels encountered by your loops that was above the (140,140,140) threshold:

As "count" is only incremented for pixels that are above the threshold, it does not contain enough information at the end of the loop to locate the (x,y) position that first/last caused it to be incremented. You need to save/remember the X,Y position of the pixels as you discover them.

You will therefore need to keep a couple of extra X,Y variables. When you encounter the first pixel above your threshold, save X,Y into firstX,firstY. Every time you encounter a pixel above the threshold, store X,Y into lastX,lastY. On exit from the loop you will then have the values you're asking for.

I'm still not sure what you'd need these values for, though. I'm wondering if you are actually trying to find a rectangle that encloses all pixels above the threshold, in which case you need to do something similar to the above, but treat X and Y independently. start with (e.g.) minX=9999, maxY=9999, maxX=0, maxY=0. When a pixel is above your threshold, update the min/max values to accumulate the bounds of the rectangle, i.e:

```
if (X < minX) minX = X;
if (Y < minY) minY = Y;
if (X > maxX) maxX = X;
if (Y > maxY) maxY = Y;
```

Then at the end of the scan, you will have the two corners (minX, minY) and (maxX, maxY) that describe the rectangle which encloses all pixels above the threshold value.

Comment: @ Jason, i had this but didn't add in code                           Xmin = Math.Min(minX, X); Currently i am doing that but the values come different based on initialization values, So i thought getting the X,Y @ position 0 , would be the start point of a line and maxX, maxY would be the end ones